# jQuery conflicts with in multiple plugins

Tags: jquery

I am using liteAccordion Plugin and amazon scoller which uses different js versions.

here is my code

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>var jQuery132 = $.noConflict(true);</script>
```

and now i include other version of js 
 and this is code for liteaccorindn plugin

```
 <script type="text/javascript">



     (function($){

            $('#one').liteAccordion({
                    onTriggerSlide : function() {
                        this.find('figcaption').fadeOut();
                    },
                    onSlideAnimComplete : function() {
                        this.find('figcaption').fadeIn();
                    },
                    autoPlay : true,
                    pauseOnHover : true,
                    theme : 'stitch',
                    rounded : true,
                    enumerateSlides : true
            }).find('figcaption:first').show(); 
            })(jQuery132);
        </script>
```

both are conflicting

here is my link [click here](http://bravo.indivar.info/sumitenterprises/)

Can anyody tell me how to resolve this conflict issue

thanks

Comment: Use just one jquery version, in your case the v1.9.1 one. Problem solved! Of course migrate plugins which work with 1.4.2 jq version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jquery no-conflict

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Now you can use $j instead of $ in your jquery code.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/